# Cannot find registerAnimation on menu controller

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to register ion-menu animation but in menu controller i cannot register animation using registeranimation method because it says   it is not available.

They removed menu type from MenuController.

`class MenuBeautyType extends MenuType {
   constructor(menu, plt) {
       super(plt);
       let openedX = ((menu.width() * (menu.isRightSide ? -1 : 1)) - (menu.width() * 15 / 100)) - 45 + 'px';
       var contentOpen = new Animation(plt, menu.getContentElement());
       contentOpen.fromTo('translateX', '0px', openedX);
       contentOpen.fromTo('scale', 1, 0.9);
       this.ani.add(contentOpen);
   }`
Any alternave to achieve this.

Comment: add code also what you are trying.

Comment: @keminkasundra how can any one to know where you have stuck?

Comment: I want to know that how I can register animations on menu in ionic 4.
in ionic 3 we can register it using registerAnimation but on ionic 4 that is not available on menu controller.